# ServiceStack's SerializeFn custom serializer/deserializers - sticks across requests?

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-text

I'm using ASP.Net with MVC, and would like to have custom SerializeFn for only certain requests. It looks like the JsConfig stuff is static, and I do see the JsConfig.BeginScope() stuff to keep the config scoped, but it doesn't seem to apply to the custom serializers/deserializers. If I define a custom SerializeFn, is it going to stick around across requests because it's static? If so, is there some way to stop that from happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Custom SerializerFn's are static and not overridable in [JsConfigScope scoped configuration](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Text/JsConfigScope.cs) so they do apply to all requests.

As custom serializers can't be limited in scope, one solution would be to map it to a custom type and attach the serializer to that:

```
public class CustomPoco : Poco {}

JsConfig<CustomPoco>.SerializerFn = //...;
```

So when you need special serialization you can map it to your custom type and serialize that:

```
var customType = dto.ConvertTo<CustomPoco>();

var jsonWithCustomSerialization = customType.ToJson();
```